# it is possible by means of a pipeline of Microsoft devops to restore a backup .bak in a resource of SQL Server in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, devops, devops-services

The backup `.bak` is hosted on a storage account. I need to perform an automatic restore through an Azure Devops pipeline on a Microsoft Azure SQL Server resource.

[image: I have the following as seen in the picture:]

And this is where I must add the task for the automatic restore.

[image: And this is where I must add the task for automatic restore]

What task should i be using to do the automatic restore

Or if you know in another way how to do the restoration it also works for me.

Comment: The point is Azure SQL database doesn't support restore from .bak file, the pipeline  couldn't work.

Comment: Azure SQL Database does not currently support restoring from a .bak file. If you can get the database backup as a .bacpac instead of .bak, you should be able to restore it from Azure DevOps pipeline.

Comment: 1. Having the backup .bacpac, what task can I use for the restoration?
2. Is it possible to restore that .bak in an azure virtual machine resource?

Comment: @jhoanna Have you checked the following reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

To import `BACPAC` file you may use [SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment?view=azure-devops) and if you want to restore database hosted on VM you may use [`SQLPACKAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) which is installed on Windows based MS Hosted agents. Please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/sql-server-actions?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) too. To find SQL Package you may use this [script](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PublishDacPac/1.0.2.2902/Content/public%5CGet-SqlPackagePath.ps1). You may also consider using FAKE tool and theirs [SQL Package wrapper](https://fake.build/sql-sqlpackage.html). Here you have [my blog post](http://thecodemanual.pl/2019/12/23/DB-deployments-with-Fake-Sql-SqlPackage.html) about this.

If you have your `DACPAC` file on storage account you have to download it first, but for this you may use [AzureCliTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) and [az storage file copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file/copy?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.

the scenario is as follows:
I have a .dacpac in a storage account, without having to download it I would like to restore it to the VM. it's possible? I am making use of the task: "Deploy an Azure SQL Database using DACPAC or run scripts using SQLCMD"
I would appreciate an orientation of how I can route so that it takes the .dacpac of the storage account.

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to download it first. Please check my edit as I added there some tips how to do it in an easy way.